# How to make Normals on seemingly flat surface smooth

Tags: modeling, edges, normals, geometry

[image: See the slight triangles leading from the circle to the edges of the side?]

So I'm having this problem where from certain angles this geometry is showing creases where there shouldn't be. Here's the things I've tried:

1. selecting all the geometry that should be level and scaling it across the Z axis to 0, no luck.
2. Auto smoothing the normals and marking sharp where it should be sharp, no matter what degrees I use for the smoothing it doesn't seem to make a difference.
3. Triangulating the n-gons, still didn't get rid of it.

[image: Shaded View, still gives that issue. Renders show it too.]

I've seen a lot of people have a similar issue, but usually they're using Booleans, which I'm not doing here.

[image: Maybe my geometry is trash?]

It could possibly be my geometry, maybe I'm breaking a rule there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The rule you're breaking (other than only using quads) is having non-quads (triangles and ngons) touching (neighboring) faces with different normals. You want to hide n-gons inside flat surfaces. https://i.imgur.com/zvqPJ4c.gif

Comment: yes, tris on ngons on slightly bent surfaces won't work fine. Are you allowed to use Subdivision Surface modifier? Because you could use less geometry

Answer (score 3):

Tris on ngons won't work fine on slightly bent surfaces. You could use this kind of topology:

[image]

If you can't use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier it needs a higher topology but you can keep this sort of solution:

[image]

[image]

[image]

etc...